# Does passing a certification mean I should get a raise?

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise, certification

A small background on me: I was a desktop guy for the past 6 years and I jumped upon a chance to enter windows administration (Wintel Administrator).
I was working as a Wintel admin for one and a half years. I recently completed a certification pertaining to my career advancement.

Due to my versatility, I am now handling 4 other agencies. Moreover, appraisal is coming soon. Is it wise to ask for a pay raise? If yes, how do I go about it?

Comment: This seems like a generic "how do I argue a raise" question which has been asked before: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: I edited the title and voted to reopen.  The crux of the question is not a duplicate of the one linked to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is wise to ask. Take your certification when you ask and show the manager. Many employers reward employees who get extra certifications with a raise. Some will actually pay for the exams. It's beneficial for the company.

> how do I go about it?

Just ask straight up at the appraisal if the company rewards things like that. They may have a set rate, or they may have none at all. It's unlikely to be negotiable unless it's a much higher cert than that though.

Comment: I agree, but that's usually a given I would think. I'm one of those that will pay for the exam if an employee upskills him/herself. Good idea to go in prepared to sell yourself though.

Answer (score 4):

I used to manage a group of 40 Windows/Cisco/Nortel techs.  Your certification is worth about as much money as the paper it was printed on.  I would seriously laugh out loud if someone wanted a raise because they just passed a standardized test.

I once had a network admin with 11 different certifications (well known) including 5 of the Cisco variety.  My new hires helped him solve basic problems.  Yes he knew the command to change something but you can also google that.  He passed his tests by cramming for them and retaking them as much as he could until he passed them.  On the Cisco ones he averaged passing on the 5th one (he told me all of this on his exit review).

Why did he leave?  Because I refused to give him a dime more after he passed 4 more certifications.  Literally I had a 10 second conversation in my head and there was no f'ing way he was going to get more.  You want to make more than show more value to your team, do better work, fix things that others can't, be faster.  If certification helps then that is awesome.

To me certification can be a learning mechanism, however nothing beats doing it every day.  When we are configuring WAN routers and connecting Juniper devices to Cisco - guess what?  This isn't supported by Juniper cert or Cisco cert (at least at that time).  They would have never learned about it even though it was are common configuration.  There were complex procedures in setting up the routing tables and if they would have followed their certification knowledge they would take down our network.

**Work knowledge/performance = raise at current job**

**Certification = raise at next job**

So ask for the raise if you deserve it.  If you have a non-tech manager then fine throw out the new certification.  A tech manager won't care though and you mentioning your wanting a raise solely due to certification seems almost like a tactical threat of leaving because you are worth more on the market.  In my opinion with a tech manager I would just stick to the facts about your work performance and knowledge at what your group does or wants to do.

Comment: I like your answer.
Work knowledge/performance = raise at current job
Certification = raise at next job
True enough, my manager only cares about how much revenue he gets, and tries to cut cost at every possible way.

Comment: @Newbie - He should care about how you help the group.  It is certainly possible that after studying for certification you bring something extra to the group but this should be displayed before an increase.

Comment: I agree in terms of ability. But certs look good hanging on the wall though, impresses the clients. It's also something you can use in advertising for a company. So they have a very real value in that sense.

Comment: @Kilisi - They are great when searching for jobs.  I don't know about the client thing.  I have clients in all the time and they wouldn't care.  They care about meeting the guys who fix their problems quick.  These guys who work for me tend to look like the just woke up and got dressed in the dark... none have any certs.  I don't want to be too negative but overall I think certs are for people who can't prove themselves day-to-day.   If you are really good at what you do there is no reason to take certification unless employer requires it.

Comment: not arguing, you're right, but clients are important. I get a huge amount of server work just because I am formally qualified on them and charge ridiculous amounts based on a piece of paper which in reality just took me a few days studying and the expense of an exam..

Comment: @Kilisi - I totally understand it in some cases.  It took you a couple days of studying because you knew the theory already behind most of the topics.  There are people who memorize tables and just take practice tests out the ass until they pass one.  The problem is that on the cert it doesn't say "dumbass who passed by memorizing practice tests" or "knows his shit".   Don't get me wrong I have very talented people with certs and if they left they might get more than the others but I don't see any other correlation because I have tons of talent with no certs.

Comment: @Kilisi - A million dollar idea would be a random cert company.  We just show up at your workplace and test people.  They have no idea we are coming.  Then I would pay money for people with good results.

Comment: here's a true life example for you of it's worth. Bank here has it's own IT, none certified on servers (third world). Head office wants to upgrade the RAM in all 5 of their banks on two Islands over the weekend. Takes me a day and a half putting a new RAM stick in each server since I have to catch a boat and drive around. $600 an hour :-) Well worth the cert. 16 hours charged, $9600 in my pocket for putting in RAM sticks

Comment: @Kilisi - I believe you.  We pay out the ass in the carribean for field techs and it is a skip from Florida.  They might haved saved money hiring you.  One reason why cert is important in countries like that is because of the rampant lying on resumes... i know...

Answer (score 2):

It shall be part of an overall strategy. You have to prove that your performance today is beyond you current pay level.

The thing to negociate there(unless pay scale is carved in stone depending on your certification), is to say "my current pay level was defined against my old level of performance. my new level of performance is better, for the following reasons - blabla based on certification & a few real life examples, like your extended responsabilities".

a certification alone, in itself, is nothing in my book. [Some even think it's negative](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CertificationCompetenceCorrelation.html). But this is alone. If it's a part of a global strategy to get better, you can sell it as a part of a package that means you took a bigger dimension recently.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you not rely purely on the certification as justification to ask for a pay raise - but definitely do include it as part of the discussion!

I would suggest something along these lines (adjusted to fit your personal tone and culture):

> For the first six years I worked here I was just a desktop guy. A year
>   and a half ago I took the opportunity to become a Wintel
>   administrator, and things have been going really well! [Giving a
>   concrete, short, example or two would be great.] I've even taken the
>   initiative to get certified as a [technical certification name here].
>   In my new role I've been able to offer a much greater value to the
>   company than in my own position, and I think my salary should be
>   changed to reflect that.

Remember: a salary increase is not a gift, reward, or payment for a certification. Companies pay ***the job you do***, not you as a person. Your certification, experience, and new position - and hopefully positive opinion of the work you've been doing - together make the case that your old salary is no longer appropriate.

The job you are doing will always be worth more than any piece of paper or credential. The right papers sure can help you get closer to what you are worth, though!